# Error with Create App Packages CompileXaml

Tags: visual-studio

I'm getting the following error while Creating App Packages for MS Store.

**The "CompileXaml" task returned false but did not log an error.   XXXXXDuo.UWP**

There is no other information, I'm using VS 2019 Community 16.7.2.  I haven't tried a repair or re-install hoping to get an answer here first.

Comment: Did a VS  repair, created x86 appx, but error occurred with the x64 and ARM package creation process.